# Deleting multiple records from mysql based on a unique id and non-unique id

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete, records

I'm new to MySQL and am having trouble converting a SQL statement over and would like some help if at all possible.

The run down is that I need to be able to delete items from one table based on a last login date, unfortunately I have no control over the table design (which is flawed) and must compare a characterID to a characterUID and LastLogin date in order to delete items from another table that only tracks objects by charcaterID (non-unique).

Here is what I have so far

```
DELETE FROM object_data WHERE CharacterID IN (
    SELECT CharacterID FROM object_data 
    WHERE CharacterID IN (
        SELECT CharacterID FROM character_data
            WHERE LastLogin < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
            AND PlayerUID NOT IN (
                SELECT PlayerUID FROM character_data 
                    WHERE LastLogin > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))))
```

The error I get is 1093.  You can't specify target table 'object_date' from update in FROM clause.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try it now:

```
DELETE FROM object_data WHERE CharacterID IN (
    SELECT CharacterID FROM  (
        SELECT CharacterID FROM character_data
            WHERE LastLogin < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
            AND PlayerUID NOT IN (
                SELECT PlayerUID FROM character_data 
                    WHERE LastLogin > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)))y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes SQL barfs if you don't name the sub-query table name

```
DELETE FROM object_data 
WHERE CharacterID IN 
(
  SELECT CharacterID 
  FROM object_data 
  WHERE CharacterID IN 
  (
    SELECT CharacterID 
    FROM character_data
    WHERE LastLogin < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
    AND PlayerUID NOT IN 
    (
       SELECT PlayerUID 
       FROM character_data 
       WHERE LastLogin > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)  
    ) AS t1
  ) AS t2
) AS t3
```